# faild to move the element in between?

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, javascript-objects, p5.js

i have  been try to solve the sudoku with Blacktracking algo, everything is good, canvar is called and i able to see the number but the things is number are not moving i.e the logic is not exectuing
`current.i === 0;` is where i'm get the error! even i have declared a sperate variable for the num also the problem is not sloved. only if i remove the .num `current == 0` than its not showing any error but still the number is not moving

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QX45W.png)

```
var cell = [];
var stack = [];
var sudoku =  [2,3,0,9,4,0,6,7,0,
               8,0,0,3,2,5,9,1,4,
               9,0,0,7,6,0,3,2,0,
               1,0,0,0,0,0,7,9,2,
               5,0,3,2,1,0,4,8,6,
               4,0,0,6,8,0,5,3,1,
               7,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,9,
               6,5,9,8,7,2,1,4,3,
               3,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,7];
var current;
var number = 1;

function setup(){
    createCanvas(450,450);
    var a=0;
    var b=0;
    for(var i=0;i<81;i++){
        if(a%9==0 && i!=0){
            b = b+50;
            a = 0;
        }
        each[i] = new each(a,b,i,sudoku[i]);
        a = a+50;
    }
    current = cell[0];
}

function draw(){
    background(10);
    for(var i=0;i<81;i++){
        each[i].show();
    }

    if(current.num === 0){ //the error is typeerror can't read the property of num 

        if(! sameColumn(current.i,number) && ! sameRow(current.i,number) && ! sameSquare(current.i,number) && number<(10)){
            current.num = number;
            stack.push(current);
            number = 0;
            current.each[current.i+1];
        }
        else {
            if(number > 8){
            current.num = 0;
            current = stack.pop();
            number = current.num;
            current.num = 0;
        }
        } 
    }
    else{
        current = each[current+1];
        number = 0;
    }
    number++;
}

function each(a,b,i,num){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.i = i;
        this.num = num;
        this.show = function(){
            noFill();
            stroke(255);
            rect(this.a,this.b,50,50);
            textSize(32);
            text(this.num,a+12,b+40);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty much straight forward. `current = cell[0];` becomes undefined since you defined `cell` as an empty array and didn't manipulated it after that.

From what I have observed so far, many parts of your code logically does not work, for example,

```
same Column(current.i,number) && ! sameRow(current.i,number) && ! sameSquare(current.i,number)
```

will definitely throw you an error is it is executed (it is not since the execution does not reach to that line), unless you have a separate js file that contains these functions.

Another one is

```
current = cell[current+1];
```

if the `current` variable is to store the cell object, it does not make sense to add 1 to it, and vice versa.

Now I believe this is how setup function was meant to look like:

```
function setup(){
    createCanvas(450,450);
    var a=0;
    var b=0;
    for(var i=0;i<81;i++){
        if(a%9==0 && i!=0){
            b = b+50;
            a = 0;
        }
        cell[i] = new Cell(a,b,i,sudoku[i]); //changed each[i] to cell[i], also renamed the 'each' class
        a = a+50;
    }
    current = cell[0];
}
```

If possible, please edit in a little more information about what exactly does your code do. Cheers :)